# how to get image base64 from jsonp?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, sencha-touch-2

I have my backend with spring and hibernate and I have a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void updateResource(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        int resource=0;
        String cb = request.getParameter("callback");

        try {
            resource = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("resource"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             logger.info(e.getMessage());
             Util.getJSONP(cb, false, e.getMessage(), "", response);
             return;

        }


        Resources rs = customerService.getResource(resource);
        rs.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
        rs.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));       
        rs.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
        rs.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
        rs.setState(request.getParameter("state"));
        rs.setZip(request.getParameter("zip"));
        rs.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
        rs.setPhoneMobile(request.getParameter("phoneMobile"));
        rs.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));     
        rs.setImage(request.getParameter("image"));
        rs.setLastUpdate(new Date());       
        String dobString = request.getParameter("dob");

        if (Util.validateDate(dobString)) {
            rs.setDob(Util.getDate(dobString));
        }
        else{
            logger.info("Invalid Format Date");
            Util.getJSONP(cb, false, "Invalid format date", "", response);
            return;
        }       

        resourceService.updateResource(rs);

        Util.getJSONP(cb, true, "success", "", response);


    }
```

The new requirement is that you can add an image. 
the frontend is made with Sencha Touch and it is sent me a picture in base64. 
I have read that I have to change my method GET to POST.
I changed my method to POST and it's not working.

My model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="resource")
public class Resources {

    @Id
    @Column(name="resource_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int resourceId;

    @Column(name="first_name",length=45)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name",length=45)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="phone",length=20)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="phone_mobile",length=20)
    private String phoneMobile;

    @Column(name="address",length=100)
    private String address;

    @Column(name="zip",length=20)
    private String zip;

    @Column(name="city",length=30)
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state",length=30)
    private String state;

    @Column(name="geox",length=20)
    private String geox;

    @Column(name="geoy",length=20)
    private String geoy;

    @Column(name="email",length=150)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="last_update")
    private Date lastUpdate;

    @Column(name="dob")
    private Date dob;

    @Column(name="image", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String image;
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by not working?

Comment: Also,resource = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("resource")); what is this doing here? is there a form being submitted on the client? If so, you can use @ModelAttribute to map the form into a server side form object.

Comment: @Zeus but the form is in sencha this not matter?

Comment: Are you using the form mentioned here? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/guide/forms If, so, Yes, it does not matter, you can use @ModelAttribute to map the form elements to object.